Is it possible to convert a JavaScript EventSource object (its number and string properties) to JSON?
I am curious how JavaScript EventSource and other similar objects having number and string properties can be converted to JSON.
I have tried some stuff with JSON.stringify(...) and eventSource.entries() but I get empty JSON.
I know that I can simply console.log(eventSource).
I am curious if I can make it a JSON not using console.log(...).

Host objects are rarely serializable, EventSource is not an exception.

@Teemu, does it mean the only way to get certain properties of such objects is by known property names?
A side note:
Then it is interesting how console.log(...) does the stuff.
I can see it works the same way in my Firefox and Opera finely printing EventSource objects to browser console.

Object.entries(eventSource) should work, just like any other object.

@Barmar, I get an array of length 0 whenever I try console.log(Object.entries(new EventSource("<sseurl>"))); or simply Object.entries(new EventSource("<sseurl>")); in my browser console.

Object.entries() only returns enumerable properties. I guess EventSource's properties aren't enumerable.

As EventSource instance doesn't have any own properties, you've to extract the properties from the prototype. However, if some of the properties are not enumerable, hence we can use getOwnPropertyDescriptors to get also the non-enumerable properties. The said method returns the keys, and also descriptor data, which is irrelevant to our task. To include correct data to the resulting JSON, we use replacer parameter of JSON.stringify. Something like this:


function serialize (obj) {
  const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
  return JSON.stringify(keys, (k, v) => k === '' ? v : obj[k], 4);
}

const eSrc = new EventSource('https://www.example.com');

console.log(serialize(eSrc));



We don't need to filter values (ex. exclude methods), as native JSON.stringify does it for us automatically. In the case of EventSource, there's no serializable non-enumerable properties, but the code can be used to serialize any prototype, which could contain such properties.

Thank you! Works perfect even when I put it into an HTML (not to console.log(...)).
Just curious if call Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) incurs any performance penalty because of some JavaScript intrinsics I may be not aware of. Does it?

@AlexanderItes I'm not aware of any performance issues these methods could cause. Executing the replacer function when stringifying takes a bit more time than strigifying without it, but the used extra time is negligible. Populating a separate result object to serialize would probably be more time consuming operation.

You can extract all properties with walking the prototype chain and collecting properties you want.
Use Object.getOwnPropertyNames() for that.
For example I collect all primitive properties here:


const getAllProps = (e, self = e) => {
  if(!e) return;
  const own = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).reduce((r, name) => {
    const val = self[name], type = typeof val;
    if(type !== 'object' && type !== 'function') r[name] = val;
    return r;
  }, {});
  return Object.assign(own, getAllProps(Object.getPrototypeOf(e), self));
}

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(getAllProps(e), null, 2));
});
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
Just click at any place




My best attempt so far has been to use JSON.stringify(...) putting my own newly created object created from object properties of an EventSource object I can see in console.log(eventSoure) output.
I doubt if it is of any practical value.
Just wanted to see it updated on the page and not in browser console.

Of course, properties CONNECTING, OPEN and CLOSE are just a set of possible values of readyState property that are added solely to see them on the page as well.


const eventSource = new EventSource("https://example.com"); // will close immediately
setInterval(
  () => {
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "<pre>" +
    JSON.stringify({
      addEventListener: eventSource.addEventListener, // native code skipped/not shown
      CLOSED: eventSource.CLOSED,
      CONNECTING: eventSource.CONNECTING,
      onerror: eventSource.onerror,
      onmessage: eventSource.onmessage,
      onopen: eventSource.onopen,
      OPEN: eventSource.OPEN,
      readyState: eventSource.readyState,
      url: eventSource.url,
      withCredentials: eventSource.withCredentials
    }, null, 2) + "</pre>";
  },
  1000
 );
<div style="background:lightgrey"></div>



